# UPDATE INNER JOIN WHERE Condition

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, where-clause

I can't proceed to my next task, my problem is that I don't know how to match the returned value of my DGV to TABLE.

This is how I load my combobox with value/display member:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5V9PS33\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Farmacia;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,ProductName FROM Product", con);
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
dt.Load(reader);
cmbProductName.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbProductName.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
cmbProductName.DataSource = dt;
cmbProductName.Text = "";
```

This is how I add value from my database and my DGV:

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", cmbSupplier.SelectedValue.ToString());
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNameID", cmbProductName.SelectedValue.ToString());
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",txtQuantity.Text);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", txtUnitPrice.Text);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Markup", txtMarkup.Text);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellingPrice", txtSellingPrice.Text);
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here's my code for "Receiving an Order" UPDATE:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5V9PS33\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Farmacia;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("DELETE From PurchaseOrder WHERE ProductNameID = '"+dgvCategory.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString()+"'", con);
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Received");
```

Populating the DGV Load/Refresh:

```
private void frmPurchaseOrder_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5V9PS33\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Farmacia;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Supplier,ProductName,PurchaseOrder.Quantity,PurchaseOrder.UnitPrice,PurchaseOrder.Markup,PurchaseOrder.SellingPrice FROM PurchaseOrder Inner Join Supplier ON Supplier.ID = PurchaseOrder.SupplierID Inner Join Product ON Product.ID = PurchaseOrder.ProductNameID", con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Supplier", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(float));
        dt.Columns.Add("Markup", typeof(float));
        dt.Columns.Add("SellingPrice", typeof(float));
        dt.Load(reader);

        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            string Supplier = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            string ProductName = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            string Quantity = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            string UnitPrice = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            string Markup = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[4].ToString();
            string SellingPrice = dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[5].ToString();
            string[] row = { Supplier, ProductName, Quantity, UnitPrice, Markup, SellingPrice };
            dgvCategory.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

My DGV will only return string or name of the "Product".

Here's my FullProduct Table
[Table HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4Si.jpg)

Window form design [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NabTo.jpg)

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is you don't know how to get the ProductNameID? What is the code populating the DGV?

Comment: hey @GiorgosAltanis check my new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time since I last worked on such applications, my apologies if something is not completely right...

Of course the ProductName is returned, since `dgvCategory.SelectedCells[1]` is the second cell of the row, and this corresponds to the second field from your query, which is  `ProductName`. You need to do some modifications:

Fetch the `ID` column as well, for example:

`SELECT Product.ID as pid, Supplier, ...`

and add it to your data table (`pid` is the alias I chose above):

`dt.Columns.Add("pid", typeof(int));`

Then add the ìd value as a tag of the data row:

```
row.Tag = dt["pid"].value;
dgvCategory.Rows.Add(row);
```

Finally, you can use this ID (saved as `Tag` on the row):

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("DELETE From PurchaseOrder WHERE ProductNameID = '"+dgvCategory.SelectedCells[1].RowIndex.Tag.ToString()+"'", con);
```

Note that I cannot test any of the above, so perhaps you need to do some research.

Comment: The "Tag" approach is not necessarily the best one; you could add a `hidden` column in the dgv with the product id value and then access this value (see the relevant documentation to see how).

Comment: Thanks bro! very helpful. with that approach, i manage to normalized all of my tables. btw the tablename.column name as column name really helped me alot! thanks!